# What causes OpenJPA logging The Entity was enhanced at some level, but current level of enhancement is something else

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, byte-code-enhancement

What might be cause of this and what does it mean? I just byte-code enhanced my entities and ran the application. On openjpa startup i get this info in log:

```
3145  desktop  INFO   [Thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - The Entity "desktop.dto.Funeral" was enhanced at level "121 008 823", but the current level of enhancement is "196 634 845".
3148  desktop  INFO   [Thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - A down level Entity was detected and logged. Please enable RUNTIME trace to see all down level Entities.
```

No problems detected from my point of view.

pom plugins in Maven:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>desktop/model/*.class</includes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you use Maven or Ant tasks for the enhancement step?

Comment: @MWiesner i used Maven for enhancement step. See added code.